# Payara - connect to the mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, payara

Payara 5.2020.2, JDK 11
Trying to connect to the mysql database.

Create JDBC Connection Pool:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNBjH.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6OUj.jpg)

I do Ping:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqUr1.jpg)

Stack trace:

```
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:356)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:335)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar
copy to folder:
C:\Development\payara520202\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext

What else haven't I done?

In file mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar
path Datasource Classname:
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
I changed the path.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkAow.jpg)

But it didn't help.
The error is the same.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace, right now, you have provided just the bottom of the stacktrace without any actual error messages.

Comment: Not sure if it is the cause of the problem (given the lack of exception information), but `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MySqlDataSource` is not a `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource`, either you need to select `javax.sql.DataSource`, or use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MySqlConnectionPoolDataSource`